# How to get same Scroll position on Staggered Grid Layout on back pressed from another activity which was showing detail of the post

Tags: android, onpause, gridlayoutmanager, onrestoreinstancestate

**I want to know how to save scroll position and restore scroll position, if I come from another activity with onbackpressed button. I m stuck in this and tried many ways in last some days, but all went in vain. Any help will be much appreciated.**

Following is my Activity.class

```
    private ImageButton mhomebtn;
    private ImageButton mexplorebtn;
    private ImageButton mcamerabtn;
    private ImageButton mstorebtn;
    private ImageButton mprofilebtn;
    private RecyclerView mexplore_page;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mgrid;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabaseLike;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabaseSave;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabasefollow;
    private DatabaseReference mdatabasefollowers;
    private boolean mProcessSave = false;
    private boolean mProcessLike = false;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private String mCurrent_state;
    private Animation mslide_up;
    private static int mPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_explore);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Explores");
        mdatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Like");
        mdatabaseSave = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saved");
        mdatabasefollow = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Following");
        mdatabasefollowers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Followers");
        mdatabasefollowers.keepSynced(true);
        mdatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        mdatabaseSave.keepSynced(true);
        mdatabasefollow.keepSynced(true);
        mhomebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homebtn);
        mexplorebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.explorebtn);
        mcamerabtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camerabtn);
        mstorebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.storebtn);
        mprofilebtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profilebtn);
        mslide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
        mslide_up.setAnimationListener(this);
        mgrid = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mgrid.setReverseLayout(true);
        mexplore_page = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.explore_page);
        mexplore_page.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mexplore_page.setLayoutManager(mgrid);

        mCurrent_state = "not_following";

        mhomebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                startActivity(new Intent(ExploreActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });
        mexplorebtn.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_explore_blue);         

        mcamerabtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                startActivity(new Intent(ExploreActivity.this, CameraActivity.class));
            }
        });

        mstorebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                startActivity(new Intent(ExploreActivity.this, StoreActivity.class));
            }
        });

        mprofilebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    
                startActivity(new Intent(ExploreActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Explores, ExploreViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Explores, ExploreViewHolder>(
                Explores.class,
                R.layout.explore_row,
                ExploreViewHolder.class,
                mdatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final ExploreViewHolder viewHolder, Explores model, final int position) {

                final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
                mPosition = position;

                viewHolder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPostimage());
                viewHolder.setLikebtn(post_key);
                viewHolder.setAddgallerybtn(post_key);

                final String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                mdatabase.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String right = dataSnapshot.child("right").getValue(String.class);
                        String center = dataSnapshot.child("center").getValue(String.class);
                        String left = dataSnapshot.child("lefttop").getValue(String.class);
                        final String category = dataSnapshot.child("category").getValue(String.class);
                        final String description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                        final String heading = dataSnapshot.child("heading").getValue(String.class);

                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {    
                                startActivity(new Intent(ExploreActivity.this, DetailActivity.class));
                            }
                        });    
                        final String post_uid = dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue(String.class);        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.maddgallerybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mProcessSave = true;

                        mdatabaseSave.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (mProcessSave){

                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(post_key)){

                                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {    
                                                viewHolder.mmessagetext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                                            }
                                        },TIME_OUT);    

                                        mProcessSave = false;
                                    }else {    
                                        mdatabase.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                                DatabaseReference newSaved = mdatabaseSave.child(uid).child(post_key);

                                                newSaved.child("postimage").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("postimage").getValue());
                                                newSaved.child("heading").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("heading").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {    
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }    
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                                            }
                                        });
                                        mProcessSave = false;    
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                            }
                        });    
                    }
                });

                mdatabaseLike.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {    
                        long likecounts = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        mdatabase.child(post_key).child("likecounts").setValue(likecounts);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                    }
                });

                mdatabase.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {  
                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("likecounts")){    
                            int count = dataSnapshot.child("likecounts").getValue(int.class);
                        }else {    
                            Toast.makeText(ExploreActivity.this, "Post has been deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                        }

                        String post_uid = dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
                        viewHolder.midtext.setText(post_uid);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.mlikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mProcessLike = true;    
                        mdatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {    
                                if (mProcessLike){    
                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){    
                                        mdatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();    
                                        mProcessLike = false;
                                    } else {    
                                        mdatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());    
                                        mProcessLike = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };    
        mexplore_page.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {    
    }

    public static class ExploreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;
        ImageButton mlikebtn;
        ImageButton maddgallerybtn;
        TextView mmessagetext;
        DatabaseReference mdatabaseLike;
        DatabaseReference mdatabaseSave;
        TextView midtext;
        DatabaseReference mdatabasefollow;
        DatabaseReference mdatabasefollowers;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        TextView mrighttext;
        TextView mcentertext;
        TextView mlefttext;
        TextView mheadinghere;
        TextView mfollow;
        TextView mdescription;
        TextView mcategory;
        TextView mlocation;
        TextView mcameraused;
        DatabaseReference mdatabase;
        ScrollView mdetailscroll;


        private static final int TIME_OUT = 100;
        public ExploreViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            mheadinghere = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.headinghere);
            mfollow  = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.follow);
            mdescription = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.deschere);
            mcategory = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            mlocation = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            mcameraused = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cameraused);
            mlikebtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.likebtn);
            maddgallerybtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.addgallerybtn);
            mmessagetext = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.messagetext);
            mdatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Like");
            mdatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
            mdatabaseSave = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saved");
            mdatabaseSave.keepSynced(true);
            midtext = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.idtext);
            mdatabasefollow = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow");
            mdatabasefollow.keepSynced(true);
            mdatabasefollowers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Followers");
            mdatabasefollowers.keepSynced(true);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Explores");
            mdetailscroll = (ScrollView) mView.findViewById(R.id.detailscroll);

        }

        public void setAddgallerybtn (final String post_key){

            mdatabaseSave.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {    
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).hasChild(post_key)){    
                        maddgallerybtn.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_assignment_turned_in);
                    }else {    
                        maddgallerybtn.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_assignment_returned);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                }
            });
        }

        public void setLikebtn (final String post_key){    
            mdatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){    
                        mlikebtn.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_favorite_red);
                    } else {    
                        mlikebtn.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_favorite_border);    
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
                }
            });    
        }

        public void setPostimage (final Context ctx, final String postimage){    
            final ImageView mpostimage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.postimage);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(postimage).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(mpostimage, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {    
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {    
                    Picasso.with(ctx).load(postimage).into(mpostimage);
                }
            });
        }
    } 
}
```

This is the Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.selftize.snapblink.ExploreActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/explore_page"
        android:layout_above="@+id/id_views">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/id_views"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomoption"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/bottomoption">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/homebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/explorebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_explore" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/camerabtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/storebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_store" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profilebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_person" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**If you want to know anything else apart than available information, please ask me and help me to achieve it.**

Comment: Are you finishing your previous activity while going towards another activity?

Comment: No. I just used startactivity(new intent(oneactivity.this, newactivity.class));

Answer (score 2):

try Overriding the following methods

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        recyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("statekey");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    recyclerViewState = mexplore_page.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();//save
    outState.putParcelable("statekey", recyclerViewState);
}
```

and dont forget to declare

```
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
```

and then add onResume like this

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (recyclerViewState != null) {
        mexplore_page.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it's still same. do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: try to set a debug point on onSaveInstanceState check if the method is getting called and if yes check whether the saved value of recyclerViewState is used in onRestoreInstanceState when the view is restored